# Can CPU-process write to memory(UVA) in GPU-RAM allocated by other CPU-process?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, virtual-address-space

When we use nVidia GPU we can use UVA (unified virtual addressing) as on the picture. But we can use GPU+UVA from different CPU-processes with different contexts.

Will be UVA use the same Page-Table (virtual address <-> physical address) for UVA in all CPU-processes(contexts), look like as it done for kernel-space addressing, or for each of CPU-process will be created own Page-Table in their address space of this process (i.e. CPU-process can not write to memory(UVA) in GPU-RAM allocated by other CPU-process)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different CPU processes have [different process-based](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html) virtual to physical pointer mappings.  Therefore a (virtual) pointer created in one CPU process cannot be reliably used in another process.  UVA has no control over harmonizing separate CPU process virtual mappings.

Comment: i.e. UVA-pointers from different CPU processes located in different Page-Table and in different virtual address spaces? But `cudaHostAllocPortable` isn't what we talking about? "cudaHostAllocPortable: The memory returned by this call will be considered as pinned memory by all CUDA contexts, not just the one that performed the allocation." http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html#g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c

Comment: `cudaHostAllocPortable` is associated with a host memory allocation, not a "GPU-RAM" allocation.

Comment: Ok. Does it mean that `cudaHostAllocPortable` I can use to share host-memory between two devices (GPUs)?